# What does link function in perl do?

Tags: perl, symlink

If I do this in perl:

```
link myfile.html index.html
```

It seems to just copy `myfile.html` to `index.html`.  Is this the intended behaviour?

I was hoping to do the equivalent of this in unix:

```
ln -s myfile.html index.html
```

Answer (score 5):

It creates a *hard* link, just like `ln` without the `-s` switch.

You might be seeking the [symlink](https://perldoc.pl/functions/symlink) function.